Sending SPL Token from PDA to ATA Problem
I have codes for transfer USDC from ATA to PDA and PDA to ATA. Also i have counter for people to be able create PDAs more than one. Counter was u8 at before. Then i realized one people only can create PDA 0-255 then i have updated u8 to u32. After then i can't get USDC from PDA to ATA.
Error is: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account.
I guess it caused by i couldn't create seed correctly in usdctoreciever function.
Here is codes transfer:
         let assigned_counter_info = &ctx.accounts.statepda.assigned_counter.to_be_bytes();
        let bump_vector = _bump1.to_le_bytes();
        let amount = ctx.accounts.statepda.pda_total_amount;
        //let dep = &mut ctx.accounts.deposit_token_account.key();
        let sender = ctx.accounts.statepda.owner;
        let inner = vec![
            sender.as_ref(),
            assigned_counter_info.as_ref(),
            sender.as_ref(),
            STATE_TAG,
            bump_vector.as_ref(),
        ];
        let outer = vec![inner.as_slice()];

            let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.tokenpda.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.wallet_to_deposit_to.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.statepda.to_account_info(),
            };

            let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                transfer_instruction,
                outer.as_slice(),
            );

            msg!("trasnfer call start");
            anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;


Here is state account init:
    #[account(
            init,
            payer = owner,
            seeds=[owner.key.as_ref(),&(counter_pda.count + 1).to_le_bytes(),owner.key().as_ref(),STATE_TAG],
            bump,
            space=8 + 1 + 8 + 32 + 32 + 14 + 4 + 33 + 1 + 32 + 8,

        )]
    statepda: Account<'info, State>,

this one init for token:
    #[account(
            init,
            seeds = [owner.key.as_ref(),&(statepda.assigned_counter).to_le_bytes() ,owner.key().as_ref()],
            bump,
            payer = owner,
            token::mint = mint,
            token::authority = statepda,
        )]
    pub tokenpda: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,


From your code, you are initializing a token account and not an Associated Token Account.
Although, not secure, The first change I would recommend is using init_if_needed constraint to avoid account already initialized errors
Second, change the ATA initialization to this
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = owner,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = state_pda,
    )]
    pub tokenpda: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

You can then avoid using the seeds and instead call the getAssociatedTokenAddressSync from the JS/TS solana/spl-token package like this
let tokenpda = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
                    mint,
                    statepda,
                    true
                ),

The final change would be regarding transferring the token and using the statepda as the authority
let bump = &[statepda.bump]; // assuming in you statepda account you created a field called bump. Significantly reduces CUs used
let signer_seeds = &[&[owner.key.as_ref(),&(counter_pda.count + 1).to_le_bytes(),owner.key().as_ref(),STATE_TAG, bump][..]];

 let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                transfer_instruction,
                signer_seeds,
            );



i guess you forget to add "bump" into signer_seeds ?

now i getting Provided seeds do not result in a valid address but problem may caused by not empty state_pda? state_pdate hold some data ? i need your help @jimii

update the signer seeds with the pda seeds for statepda. Maybe I missed something. Are you setting the bump correctly? could you also share the statepda address?

actually it's a little bit classified could you please share you discord or telegram adress i really want to show you all codes bro @Jimii


ctx.accounts.wallet_to_deposit_to.to_account_info()

is this marked #[account(mut)] in your Context?

yes everythink was working till i've changed counter u8 to u32
